# data.table join + update with mult='first' gives unexpected result

Tags: r, data.table

In the below example, I have a table of users and a table of transactions where one user can have 0, 1, or more transactions.  I execute a join+update with `mult='first'` on the users table to attempt to insert a column indicating the date of the first occurring transaction for each user.

```
library(data.table)  # v1.10.4

# Download data
users <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ben519/DataWrangling/master/Data/users.csv")
transactions <- transactions <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ben519/DataWrangling/master/Data/transactions.csv")

# Convert date columns to Date type
    users[, `:=`(Registered = as.Date(Registered), Cancelled = as.Date(Cancelled))]
    transactions[, TransactionDate := as.Date(TransactionDate)]

users
   UserID     User Gender Registered  Cancelled FirstTransactionDate
1:      1  Charles   male 2012-12-21       <NA>           2012-08-26
2:      2    Pedro   male 2010-08-01 2010-08-08           2013-12-23
3:      3 Caroline female 2012-10-23 2016-06-07           2016-05-08
4:      4  Brielle female 2013-07-17       <NA>                 <NA>
5:      5 Benjamin   male 2010-11-25       <NA>                 <NA>

transactions
    TransactionID TransactionDate UserID ProductID Quantity
 1:             1      2010-08-21      7         2        1
 2:             2      2011-05-26      3         4        1
 3:             3      2011-06-16      3         3        1
 4:             4      2012-08-26      1         2        3
 5:             5      2013-06-06      2         4        1
 6:             6      2013-12-23      2         5        6
 7:             7      2013-12-30      3         4        1
 8:             8      2014-04-24     NA         2        3
 9:             9      2015-04-24      7         4        3
10:            10      2016-05-08      3         4        4

##### For each user, insert the TransactionDate of the first matching row
users[transactions, FirstTransactionDate := i.TransactionDate, on="UserID", mult="first"]

# Unexpected result
users[UserID == 2]
   UserID  User Gender Registered  Cancelled FirstTransactionDate
1:      2 Pedro   male 2010-08-01 2010-08-08           2013-12-23  # <- shouldn't this be 2013-06-06?
```

Why does FirstTransactionDate `2013-12-23` get set for user 2 when an earlier transaction in the transactions table is tied to that user?  Is this a bug?

Comment: To clarify - doesn't the 5th/6th rows in `transactions` get matched to the 2nd row in `users`?

Comment: Like Mike, I'm also confused why the 5th row from `transactions` would match the 5th row from `users` when joining via UserID.  Also, I cleaned up my "Unexpected Result" section a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading the documentation for `data.table`'s `mult` more closely, it says that:

> When `i` is a `list` (or `data.frame` or `data.table`) and multiple rows in `x`
> match to the row in `i`, `mult` controls which are returned: `"all"`
> (default), `"first"` or `"last"`.

So if there are multiple rows in `x` ("users") that match to `i` ("transactions"), then `mult` will return the first row in `x`. However, in your case, there aren't multiple rows in `x` that match to `i`, rather there are multiple rows in `i` that match to `x`.

As @Arun suggested, the best option would be change around your so that `mult = "first"` is relevant:

```
users[, FirstTransactionDate := transactions[users, TransactionDate, on="UserID", mult = "first"]]

users
#   UserID     User Gender Registered  Cancelled FirstTransactionDate
#1:      1  Charles   male 2012-12-21       <NA>           2012-08-26
#2:      2    Pedro   male 2010-08-01 2010-08-08           2013-06-06
#3:      3 Caroline female 2012-10-23 2016-06-07           2011-05-26
#4:      4  Brielle female 2013-07-17       <NA>                 <NA>
#5:      5 Benjamin   male 2010-11-25       <NA>                 <NA>
```

Another option would be to change up your merge slightly:

```
users[transactions[,FirstTransactionDate := min(TransactionDate), by = UserID],
      FirstTransactionDate := FirstTransactionDate, on="UserID"]
```

I just create the first transaction date within the `transactions` dataset. This gets merged on multiple times, but it should be fine because it's always the same value for a `UserID`.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks Mike.

Comment: @Arun, thanks! Just updated my answer. I was trying to think of a good way to flip the merges. Better than my original way.